# HTML tag pair on the same line

Tags: html

Does an HTML tag opening initiation or closing need to be on the same line?

That is, does each line have to have the pair "<" and ">" on it in order for HTML to recognize it?

For example, consider the following code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<div class="box">
  <p class="item">A</p>
  <p class="item">B</p>
  <p class="item">C</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can it be written and operated as,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<div cla
        ss="box">
  <p class="it
      em">A</p>
  <p class="item">B</p>
  <p class="item">C</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice how each line does not have "<" ">" pair on it.

Comment: In your example the first p would get 2 classes "it" and "em".  Also your div would not have a class.  It would have both an empty "cla" attribute and an "ss" attribute with "box" as a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot break the element/attribute names apart but anything else is pretty flexible.  However you may see mixed results depending upon the browser if you don't comply with W3C standards. Though, most browsers are pretty forgiving these days.

Start Tags:

- The first character of a start tag must be a (<).
- The next few characters of a start tag must be the element's tag name.
- If there are to be any attributes in the next step, there must first be one or more space characters.
- Then, the start tag may have a number of attributes, the syntax for which is described below. Attributes must be separated from each other by one or more space characters.
- After the attributes, or after the tag name if there are no attributes, there may be one or more space characters. (Some attributes are required to be followed by a space. See the attributes section below.)
- Then, if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single (/). This character has no effect on void elements, but on foreign elements it marks the start tag as self-closing.
- Finally, start tags must be closed by a (>).

End Tags:

- The first character of an end tag must be a (<).
- The second character of an end tag must be a (/).
- The next few characters of an end tag must be the element's tag name.
- After the tag name, there may be one or more space characters.
- Finally, end tags must be closed by a (>).

More about W3 standards here:
https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/syntax.html#start-tags

Comment: Thanks so much. These rules are not so obvious. I also take it that the attributes after the tag can be on different lines? An exagerated scenario that is allowable could be one line for each attribute before the final closing ">".

Comment: Yes, you can break the attributes apart just not their names.  HTML element/attribute names are all single words.  So a space or new-line splits them into separate attributes.  You can split their values assuming they're encased in quotes.

Comment: You can always test how the browser interprets the HTML by inspecting the elements with the developer tools on all modern browsers to make sure the browser is recognizing your HTML the way you meant it.

Answer (score 2):

Simple logic: if there is possible to have any keyword within the tagname and it's closing (between `<tag_name and >`) then you can break word in this place. That means, that you can write something like:

```
<div 
> 
    something
</div>
```

but not:

```
<
div
>
    something
<
/ div
>
```

In the same time there is possible to have any whitespaces, tabs and newlines between open and closing tags

Answer (score 1):

A tag may span multiple lines. For example:

```
<img scr="mypic.png"
alt="example">
```

However, splitting attributes as you've shown in your example would not work (as explained by Nathan Champion in the comments).